# Checking for string null terminators in C

Tags: c, null-terminated

I know what the null-terminator in C is represented by `\0` and has the numerical value of 0. However, when I execute the following code below, the program treats the null terminator as `%`. I searched this up online but I couldn't find anyone with this issue.

```
int main(){
    char* forward = "hello";
    int forward_length = 0;
    while (*(forward++) != '\0') {
        printf("%d\n", forward_length++);
    }
    if(*forward == '%'){
        printf("Terminator Found");
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
0
1
2
3
4
Terminator Found
```

Clearly, `forward[5]` does not equal the char `%`. Can someone please let me know what is wrong with the program?

Comment: `while (*(forward++) != '\0')` This increments `forward` regardless of the conditional. When the loop ends `forward` will point one past the `'\0'` nul terminator, and dereferencing `*forward` is [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

Comment: Whoever wrote the code perhaps expects the `"%d"` string to immediately follow `"hello"` in memory, but there is no such guarantee; the code relies on undefined behavior.

Comment: Your test of `(*forward == '%')` is looking one past the null terminator, since the earlier null check post-incremented it.  So it's equivalent to using an index of 6, not 5, in the original string.  Since you're indexing past the null terminator of the string constant, it's undefined behavior, and the value could be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction leaves `forward` advanced too far. This is because the post-increment will run even if the loop condition is false (as it is inside the loop condition). The obvious fixed loop is as follows:

```
   for (;*forward != '\0'; ++forward)
       printf("%d\n", forward_length++);
```

If you prefer to keep the while loop, `--forward` after the while loop will fix it.